# PHP MySQLi Is Not Looping to Get all Rows Using Prepared Statement

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, prepared-statement

Can you please let me know why I am not able to loop through all rows and return them in arrays (each row in one are) by this code?

```
$id= $_POST['uid'];
$rows = [];
$sql = "SELECT customerName, city, date FROM `customers` WHERE id=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($customerName, $city, $date);
 while($stmt->fetch()){
    $rows =  array($customerName, $city, $date);
 }
 echo json_encode($rows);
```

As you can see I am using `while($stmt->fetch()){}` but I am only getting the last row in `echo json_encode($rows);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use bracket syntax (`[]`) to add elements to an array. Without it you override the value in `$rows`:

```
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $rows[] =  array($customerName, $city, $date);
}
```

Comment: Thanks John Conde , but I declared the `$row` as an array already, isnt it enough? Can you please also let me know if there is a better way to do this I mean getting the data using one of MySQLi  or Prepared Statement built in functions?

Comment: It is *not* enough. PHP allows you to change the data type for variables. So unless you treat a variable like an array it will no longer be one.